# python flask join two tables and show the result in html

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://name:password@localhost/database'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    location = db.Column(db.String(55))
    series = db.relationship('Serie', backref='Serie', lazy='dynamic')


class Serie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'serie'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    series_name = db.Column(db.String(55))
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'))


@app.route('/')
def index():
    books = Book.query.join(Serie, Book.id == Serie.book_id).add_columns(Book.id, Book.title, Book.location, Serie.series_name)
    return render_template('bootstrap_table.html', title='Book Library',
                           book=books)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I can't seem to get the series_name to show up in place of the `series` when I render the html. Is the relationship to ForeignKey setup right? Or does the query need adjusting?
This is the first time trying to use two tables.

I am using jinja `{{book.title}}`, `{{book.location}}`, `{{Serie.series_name}}` to get results in HTML. Notice `series_name`  in place of series. I am trying to get `Serie.series_name` associated with the proper `book.id` in the 3rd column.

Comment: Regardless of your question, I recommend using the name "book" instead of "Serie" in the backref parameter of the relationship. The parameter defines the attribute under which the back reference to the book in the series can be reached. For example, you can use `Serie.query.first().book` to query the book that is referenced via the ForeignKey `book_id`. - At the moment I don't understand what result you expect. The statement `.with_entities(*entities)` might help you to get closer to your goal. Instead of `.add_columns(*column)` only the entities that are specified are returned in a tuple.